# Using css for replacing text on click (instead of jquery)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, click, show-hide

I'm trying to make a flashcard system. I ask a question, and when the question is clicked, it should reveal the answer and hide the question. I now use this code: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/G8BKq/)

```
<p id="shown">What is stackoverflow?</p>


<script>
$("#shown").click(function () {
    $(this).replaceWith("<p>A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.</p>" );
});
</script>
```

This works fine, but after reading [this](http://css-tricks.com/the-checkbox-hack/). I thought it may be possible to do this using only css. I've tried, but I failed.

I also would like to add some other functionality. If the answer is clicked, the question should show-up again, and the answer should be hidden.

If this is not possible with css, I would be able to fix this with jquery myself. I'm only interested in the question: if/how this is possible using only css

Comment: If you plan on adding other functionality anyway, you should just stick with the jQuery...

Comment: Changing a style and the contents of an element are two different things. With some show and hide magic it's probably possible with CSS3, but IMO you should stick with JS.

Comment: @Zenith This is the only functionality I want to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSyeD/1/)

Use this as html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle">

<label id="shown" for="toggle">
    What is stackoverflow?
</label>
<label id="hidden" for="toggle" >
   A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.
</label>
```

And this for css:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
   position: absolute;
   top: -9999px;
   left: -9999px;
}

#shown {
    display: block;
}
#hidden {
    display: none;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #hidden{
   display: block;
}

#toggle:checked ~ #shown {
   display: none;
}
```